# How to understand how many comparisons are made in the merge algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, merge

In the merge algorithm, why is the number of comparisons is at most N, and at least N/2. I thought the comparison is at most N/2, since there would be at most calls on less(aux[j], aux[i]). Or does that mean the comparison include the statements of 
if(i > mid) and else if (j > hi )? Thanks!

```
public static void merge(Comparable[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi) 
{ 
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) 
        aux[k] = a[k];

    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) 
    if(i > mid)  a[k] = aux[j++];
    else if (j > hi )  a[k] = aux[i++];
    else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++]; 
    else  a[k] = aux[i++];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, suppose you want to merge these lists together:

```
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 10
```

This work work as follows:

```
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 1 and 2, output 1

3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 3 and 2, output 2

3 5 7 9
4 6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 3 and 4, output 3

5 7 9
4 6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 5 and 4, output 4

5 7 9
6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 5 and 6, output 5

7 9
6 8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 7 and 6, output 6

7 9
8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 7 and 8, output 7

9
8 10
^
+--------------- Compare 9 and 8, output 8

9
10
^
+--------------- Compare 9 and 10, output 9


10
^
+--------------- Output 10
```

Here, there are 10 total elements and, as you can see, 9 comparisons were needed. The maximum number of compares that will be made is actually N - 1 for an N-element list, since if you alternate back and forth between one list having a larger value and the other having a larger value one comparison will be made per element being outputted (except for the very last one). The case where N / 2 comparisons are made is actually the best possible case; that happens only when all elements in one list are strictly smaller than all elements in the other.